# columns to rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like this:

| DATE | CZK | EUR | USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-25 | 25 | 15,5555684 | 4 |

And I want to turn it into this table:

| DATE | CP | mnozstvi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-25 | CZK | 25 |
| 2021-07-25 | EUR | 15,5555684 |
| 2021-07-25 | DOL | 4 |

My data.frame is much larger, this is just minimal example. I seek some versatile solution. I managed to do that by function gather() like this:

```
data.frame %>% gather(CP,,CZK,EUR,USD) %>% rename(mnozstvi = value)
```

But it changed the numbers as some of them vere decimal adn I dnt know why. Any ideae how to do that easily? thank you.

Comment: The numbers were probably changed because you have `,` instead of `.` as a decimal separator I suspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `melt` within `data.table` package

```
> melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "DATE",variable.name = "CP",value.name = "mnozstvi")
         DATE  CP mnozstvi
1: 2021-07-25 CZK 25.00000
2: 2021-07-25 EUR 15.55557
3: 2021-07-25 USD  4.00000
```

or using `stack`

```
> setDT(df)[,setNames(rev(stack(.SD)),c("CP","mnozstvi")),DATE]
         DATE  CP mnozstvi
1: 2021-07-25 CZK 25.00000
2: 2021-07-25 EUR 15.55557
3: 2021-07-25 USD  4.00000
```

Answer (score 2):

A **dplyr solution**:
This question is most suited for an answer with `pivot_longer()`, which is pretty much the modern version of `gather`.

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%pivot_longer(cols=c(CZK, EUR, USD), names_to="CP", values_to = 'mnozstvi')

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  DATE       CP    mnozstvi
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
1 2021-07-25 CZK       25  
2 2021-07-25 EUR       15.6
3 2021-07-25 USD        4
```

**data**

```
df<-data.frame(DATE=c('2021-07-25'), CZK=25, EUR=15.5555684, USD=4)
```

If your data has characters with comas`,`as separators, like this,

**data2**

```
df<-data.frame(DATE=c('2021-07-25'), CZK=25, EUR='15,5555684', USD=4)
```

You may have to do some transformation before the pivot_longer operation:

```
df%>%mutate(across(CZK:USD, ~as.numeric(str_replace_all(.x, ',', '.'))))%>%
        pivot_longer(cols=c(CZK, EUR, USD), names_to="CP", values_to = 'mnozstvi')
```